# Pass file reader data to service in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, filereader

I am using file reader to fetch the data of file upload. I am able to get the data in controller.js, but not able to pass it to the API service. The data is always passed as empty. I have updated the code as below:

//index.cshtml

```
 <input type="file" my-files="files" />
 <input type="button" name="imageUploadButton" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
```

// controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('AppController', function($scope, testAPIService, Excel, $timeout, $window, $location, $anchorScroll,$http) {


var url = "server/UploadImage/";

var config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": undefined,
        }
    };


 $scope.uploadFiles = function () {   


           var file = $scope.files[0];

        $http.post(url, file, config).then(function (response) {
             $scope.result = "SUCCESS";

             $scope.data = response.data.data;
         }).catch(function (response) {
             alert( "ERROR " + response.status);
         });
    };


});

angular.module("myApp.controllers").directive("myFiles", function ($parse) {
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on("change", function (e) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.myFiles + "=$files", { $files: e.target.files });

            scope.$apply();
            console.log(scope);
        });
    };
});

angular.module("myApp.controllers").directive("xdHref", function () {
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function (newVal) {
            newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
        });
    };
});
```

When the file is selected, "myFiles" directive is invoked, and i can see the data in console. When i click on the upload button, the below line is coming as error

```
var file = $scope.files[0];
```

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Which backend api are you using..?

Comment: The `newdata` is `undefined` because it is being assigned *asynchronously* inside the `fileReader.onload` function *after* the call to `testAPIService.postUploadImage`. Convert that asynchronous API to a $q service promise or move the service code inside the APIs callback.

Comment: Instead of converting the file to a base64 dataURL, consider sending the file as a binary. Base64 has a 33% overhead.

Comment: Hi @georgeawg. could you please provide a code sample

Answer (score 0):

### Uploading Files with AngularJS

```
  vm.upload = function() {
    $http.post(url, vm.files[0], config).
     then(function(response) {
      vm.result = "SUCCESS";
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    });
  };
```

HTML

```
<input type=file my-files="files" /><br>
<button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button><br>
```

**`my-files` Directive**

```
app.directive("myFiles", function($parse) {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("change", function (e) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.myFiles + "=$files", {$files: e.target.files});
      scope.$apply();
    });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/CqIixHWefjYmDfmJPbNF?p=preview).

Comment: Hi @georgeawg. vm.files[0] is coming as undefined for me. I have used the same code as given in demo. Error is : Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Hi @georgeawg, I have updated my code like the demo. could you please let me know, where i need to change as per your demo